# How to fix a Lint error about variable ordering (Angular 2)?

Tags: angular, tslint

I have a structure like this:

```
export class Foo {

    private variable = 'value';

    static Bar = class {

        constructor() {
        }
    };

    constructor() {
    }
}
```

Running `ng lint` gives me: `Declaration of public static member variable not allowed to appear after declaration of private instance member variable`

Ok. After swapping the order:

```
export class Foo {

    static Bar = class {

        constructor() {
        }
    };

    private variable = 'value';

    constructor() {
    }
}
```

I know get: `Declaration of private instance member variable not allowed to appear after declaration of public instance member function`

How I'm supposed to fix this Lint error?

Comment: what version of tslint do you have?

Comment: Seems to be 4.4.2

Comment: try to update to latest version 5.8.0